# WPF binding root element of xaml file does not work:

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding

I was trying to bind a dataContext to a grid (xaml below)

```
<Grid  ....    DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}"  > ...</Grid>
```

This binding did not work and I realized the getter for NewFormViewModel was never being called.

At this point in time, The grid was the root element of the xaml file.

I then placed a canvas inside the Grid and did binding on the canvas like :

```
<Grid  ....> 
  <Canvas DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}">
      ....
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The data binding worked.

Next I tried to change the grid to a canvas and do databinding agiain like this:

```
<Canvas....    DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}"  > ...</Canvas>
```

The binding stopped working again.

In the end I settled for a Grid nested inside a canvas:

```
   <Canvas....> 
      <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}">
          ....
      </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

The question is why did the binding on the root element of the xaml not work?

or Should I have not used a Canvas/Grid as a root element at all and used something like Page/UserControl?

**EDIT**

My logical tree looks somthing like this:

```
         Window   <- Data binding to object o
           |
           *
          Frame     <-Data binding to obect o inherited
           |
           *
         Canvas/Grid <- Data binding to o.NewFormViewModel failed
           |
           *
         Canvas/Grid <- Data binding to o.NewFormViewModel Succeeds
```

EDIT2:

broken xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Class="WPFEditors.NewForm"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" Height="398" Width="377"
      DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}"
     >
    <Grid  >
    <Label DataContext="Form Type" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
    <ComboBox Margin="148,22,6,347" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FormTypes}" />
    <Label Content="Description" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,58,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Heading}" ToolTip="This is pulled from the Enum defined for FormTypes" Margin="148,59,6,309" />   
    <Label Content="Version" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,95,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
    <TextBox Text="Bind this later" Margin="148,97,6,270" Height="31" />
    <Label Content="Approval Level" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
    <TextBox Height="31" Margin="148,134,6,233" Text="Bind this later" />
    <Label Content="Number of Approvals" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
    <TextBox Height="31" Margin="148,173,6,194" Text="Bind this later" />
    <Label Content="Heading" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
    <TextBox Height="31" Margin="148,212,6,155" Text="Bind this later" />
    <Label Content="Static Data Id" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
    <TextBox Height="31" Margin="148,249,6,118" Text="Bind this later" />
    <Label Content="{Binding  Path=Errors}" Background="{Binding Path=Color}" Margin="12,325,6,6" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF000019" />
    <Button Content="Create" Margin="83,294,202,78" />
    <Button Content="Create" Margin="181,294,104,78" />
    <Button Content="Create" Margin="279,294,6,78" />
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

In the above xaml the following line binds:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Heading}"
```

even though Heading is inside a property of the viewmodel that this document inherits. 
At this point  I would have expected the line:

```
 DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}"
```

to have changed the datacontext to NewFormViewModel which has no heading. All the remaining bindings fail.

If I change the beginning to :

```
<Canvas x:Class="NewForm"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" Height="398" Width="377"

     >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=NewFormViewModel}" >
```

The binding to Heading fails and the rest of the bindings start to work. This is the behaviour that I was expecting initially.

This xaml is  nested in this file :

```
<Window x:Class="WPFEditors.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Path=Heading}" Height="743" Width="1177">

    <StackPanel  >
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" >
            <MenuItem Header="New">
                <MenuItem Header="New Form" Command="{Binding Path=MenuCommand}" />
            </MenuItem>    
            <MenuItem Header="Edit Form"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FormsAvailable}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Edit Rules" />            
        </Menu>

        <Frame  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentPage}"
                LoadCompleted="Frame_LoadCompleted"
                DataContextChanged="Frame_DataContextChanged"
                Name="frame">
        </Frame>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

and the event handlers to copy the data context to the child are :

```
private void Frame_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(); 
}

private void Frame_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(); 
}

private void UpdateFrameDataContext()
{
    var content = frame.Content as FrameworkElement; 
    if (content == null) 
        return; 
    content.DataContext = frame.DataContext;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Binding in the root element should work IF there is something up in the control hierarchy (like a Window or UserControl) that holds (in its DataContext) the object owning the property you're querying (NewFormViewModel).

Comment: that is exactly what I thought first. However in all 4 examples above the control hierarchy has always been the same, that is the frame which loads the xaml file has always remained the same and the dataContext of the frame has always been the same. But for some reason the root element in the xaml does not bind while the children do. I am just curious why this is happening.. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: and since the binding works on children and dataContext is inherited by children, I think it is safe to assume that the parent will also have the same dataContext. Especially since I am using the DataContext that I set on the main Window

Comment: Could we see the complete example on how are you populating and not working.

Comment: I added the code. Has made my question incredibly large (main reason for not posting it). I hope it helps. And thanks a lot at taking the time to help me out :)

Comment: Sorry... maybe I'm missing something, but can't see the place where you put the object that provides all those properties you state. In the line 'content.DataContext = frame.DataContext;' how does 'frame.DataContext' gets its data?

Comment: The datacontext was set in the code behind file "DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();"

Comment: Ill try to make a dummy program over the weekend and see if I can recreate this issue.. Thanks for your help :)